# How to get the coordinates of the x-axis from a profile graph in Arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinates, profile

I have done already a profile graph in ArcMap drawing a diagonal line over a DEM image. Now I would like to add some point locations as it is showed in the attached figure. I set these blue points in an approximated location. However, I would like to know the UTM coordinates of the x-axis of this profile. It is to know where exactly can I match my location points in the x-axis of this graph (points which already I know their coordinates). When I export the data from this Profile Graph, the x-axis give me distance values from 0 to ~190,000 m. And what I need is the real coordinates and no distances from A to B.

Is there some method to know these x-coordinates of this profile graph?

[image]

Comment: Just export data to Excel.

Comment: @FelixIP great answer! but I want the x-coordinates (UTM values) of this profile line to know where exactly can I match my points (which already I know their coordinates) in this graph. If you see the values in the x-axis are distances in meters from 0 to X m.  Instead of distances I would like to have the UTM coordinates (longitude West-East) of this x-axis.

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood Q. Export graphic, what you call diagonal into feature and calculate start X using add geometry tool